# Generete JOOQ in Intellij IDEA progect

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea, jooq

How to do this http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.6/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/
In this https://www.dropbox.com/s/3c8whmhuy7rq237/Transport.zip?dl=0 project?
I have Firebird database TRANSPORT.FDB placed in root of project, and want to use JOOQ with it. For this I neen generate structure for this database using org.jooq.util.GenerationTool with jooq-config.xml. But I don't know how do this in IDEA.
Application using JavaFX and have multiple screens. In MainScreenController, after press Find button, i call FindSchemes method that work with database and using database information from Main class.
I download from Maven all used JOOQ libraries.

Comment: You are asking us to download a zip file to know what your project is ? Can you not describe the necessary parts of it instead ?

Comment: Project using JavaFx for UI. All "database" code in /screens/MainScreenController.findSchemes method.

Comment: There is no clear question ... "I want to do this (link given) in this (link given) project"... This board is intended so you can easily ask clearly defined questions, and entice quick responses. Try to rephrase that with short relevant pieces in-line.

Comment: I tried create new empty Maven project. Import all libraries. Placed  TRANSPORT.FDB to /src folder.

Comment: I want configure jOOQ's code generator. I create new empty Maven project and compile this plugin http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/#N27A8F. But this plugin is for posgresql, I need Firebird.

Answer (score 1):

IT WORKED!!!
I create new Maven project and change example plugin. And now application was connected to my Firebird database.

full project with database KURSOVA.FDB
username: sysdba
password: masterkey
https://www.dropbox.com/s/40wo629mejgmivn/untitled.zip?dl=0

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>transport</groupId>
  <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>transport</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>

                <!-- Specify the maven code generator plugin -->
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>

                <!-- The plugin should hook into the generate goal -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <!-- Manage the plugin's dependency. In this example, we'll use a PostgreSQL database -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Specify the plugin configuration.
                     The configuration format is the same as for the standalone code generator -->
                <configuration>

                    <!-- JDBC connection parameters -->
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:/Users/vladstarikov/Dropbox/IdeaProjects/Database/untitled/src/KURSOVA.FDB</url>
                        <user>SYSDBA</user>
                        <password>masterkey</password>
                    </jdbc>

                    <!-- Generator parameters -->
                    <generator>
                        <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.util.firebird.FirebirdDatabase</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <excludes></excludes>
                            <inputSchema></inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>org.jooq.util.maven.example</packageName>
                            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```